# PassportJS Authentication Failing every time (LocalStrategy)

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js

I'm new to SO & Node / Passport so apologies in advance. I've been trying to work through the login portion of my site using Passport (already have registration working) for several days now with no success. I've tried several tutorials and read through the documentation, but at this point am more confused than when I started.

Problem: passport.authenticate function returns "user" as false despite the information being correct according to my database (MongoDB). I'm not getting any error messages, in /dologin route, the user value is false and info value is "Missing Credentials". Let me know if there is any other information I can provide - I appreciate the help!

Attempts: I've moved my code around to different functions, files etc. Tried different solutions found online, tried the documentation examples, wrote my own methods in my models. etc.

App.js file

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'secrettexthere',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true,
  // using store session on MongoDB using express-session + connect
  store: new MongoStore({
    mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection
  })
}));

// Init passport authentication
app.use(passport.initialize());
// persistent login sessions
app.use(passport.session());



passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, user_password, done) {
   User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err,user){
     console.log('in getUserByUsername');
     if(err) throw err;
     if(!user){
       return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown user.'});
     };

     User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err,isMatch) {
       if (err) throw err;
       console.log('in comparepassword');
       if(isMatch) {
         console.log('isMatch');
         return done(null, user);
       } else { console.log('not match');
         done(null, false, {message:'Invalid username or password.'})};
     })

   });
  } ));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
 done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
 User.getUserById(id, function(err, user) {
   done(err, user);
 });
});
```

Routing File (ideally will eventually move this to my controller but just want to get it working to some extent to start)

```
router.post('/dologin', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req);
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { console.log('nomatch');
    console.log(info);
    console.log('');
    console.log(user);
    return res.redirect('/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      console.log('match match match');
      return res.redirect('/register');
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Model

```
module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback){
  var query = {username: username};
  User.findOne(query, callback);
};

module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback){
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err,isMatch){
    if (err) throw err;
    callback(null, isMatch);
  });
};

module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
  User.findById(id, callback);
};
```

Comment: if user authenticate success, it will be redirect to `login` page, right ?

Comment: On success it should redirect to the register page (just used this as a test page)